Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$ with operator norm $1$. Can $I-T$ be invertible?
Let $T$ be a bounded operator on a Banach space $X$ with operator norm $1$. Can we conclude that $I-T$ should always be singular (non-invertible)?
The theorem on convergence of Neumann series tells us $I-T$ is invertible when the norm of $T$ is less than $1$.
I am kind of questioning the limit case when the norm of $T$ is $1$.

The most boring counterexample: $T = -I$.

Perhaps you want $T\geq 0$?

If $|T|=1$ the spectrum of $T$ is contained in the closed unit ball. But it does not imply that $1$ belongs to the spectrum. In other words not every number $z$ such that $|z|\le 1$ is equal $1.$ Moreover the condition $|T|=1$ does not imply that the spectral radius is equal $1.$ It can be less than $1.$ In such case every operator $zI-T$ is invertible for $|z|=1,$ $I-T$ in particular.
